# string split on capital letters a large dataframe column

Tags: python

I have a dataframe `df1` with multiple columns. I need to separate each string in this column by capital letters; looks easy but it's not (for me).

I have tried `str.split` and `regex` but not working

```
df1['Edition Statement]=df1['Edition Statement'].str.split('A', expand=True)
df1
```

Would like to have string separated by capital letters

Comment: Possible for you to add sample input and expected output?

Comment: df['Edition Statement'] = df['Edition Statement'].str.split(r'[A-Z]')

Comment: it should be something like this:

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
df1['Edition Statement'].str.split('[A-Z]', expand=True)
```

[A-Z] is the regular expression for one capital letter.

Comment: df1['Edition Statement'].str.split('[A-Z]', expand=True) returns the following error: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

Comment: str.split and I think regex wont work as I Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

Comment: How bloody can I upload a picture to show the issue?

Comment: ٌWhat's the dtype of df1['Edition Statement']?